# Solutions to the equation $ze^{a-z}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $a \in \mathbb{R}, a>1,$ and consider the equation $$ze^{a-z}=1$$ How many solutions does this equation have in the unit disk, and how many of those solutions are real?

My attempt to solve was to use the Argument Principle on the function $f(z)=ze^{a-z}-1$, in hopes of recovering the number of zeroes that way. The integral I attempted to compute for this was $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{a-z}-ze^{a-z}}{ze^{a-z}-1}dz=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1-z}{z-e^{z-a}}dz$$

I do not know how to proceed from here, as the $e^{z-a}$ in the denominator seems problematic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as real solutions are concerned, see the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 4):

I may have the solution. On the unit disk, by the Maximum Modulus Theorem, we have: $$\left|ze^{a-z}-1-(ze^{a-z})\right|=1\leq\left|ze^{a-z}\right|=e^t, t>0$$

So by Rouche's Theorem, $ze^{a-z}-1$ has the same number of zeros as $ze^{a-z}$ in the unit disk. Since $e^{a-z}$ has no zeroes, $ze^{a-z}$ has one zero (at $z=0$ ) in the unit disk. Thus $$ze^{a-z}=1$$ has one solution in the unit disk. If $z$ is real, we have the equation $$e^x=e^ax, a>1$$

This must have a solution, because $e^a(0)=0<e^0=1$ but $e^a(1)=e^a>e^1=e.$ Since both functions are continuous, they must have a real solution somewhere in between $0<x<1$.

So the answer is that there is exactly one solution, and it is a real solution.

Comment: Another way to see that the unique zero in the unit disk must be real is to observe that $f(z) = ze^{a-z}$ is real on the real axis, so $f(\,\overline{z}\,) = \overline{f(z)}$, which implies that the non-real zeros come in conjugate pairs, so if $f$ had a non-real zero in the unit disk, it would have at least $2$.